# Agrupar registros SQL SERVER usando Distinct y Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando realizar la agrupación de registros de dos tablas usando la siguiente consulta:

```
  select distinct detrec.iddestino,
--sum(DetRec.NoBulto) as [Número de Bultos], sum(DetRec.Peso) as [Peso],
case when   enrec.OrigenEnvios=detrec.iddestino then sum(DetRec.NoBulto)
end AS NoBultoRecibido,
case when enrec.OrigenEnvios=detrec.iddestino then sum(DetRec.Peso) 
end as Peso,

case when enrec.OrigenEnvios<>detrec.iddestino   then sum(DetRec.Nobulto)
end as NoBultoEnviado,

case when enrec.OrigenEnvios<>detrec.iddestino  then sum(DetRec.Peso)
end as Peso
from Recibos EnRec
inner join RecibosDetalle DetRec on (DetRec.IdRecibo = EnRec.IdRecibo)
inner join Destinos Dest on (Dest.IdDestino = DetRec.IdDestino)
where  convert(char(15),fecharecibo,111) between '2017/01/13' and '2017/01/13' and enrec.idservicio='1'
group by EnRec.IdServicio,DetRec.Iddestino,Enrec.OrigenEnvios
```

El resultado que obtengo de la consulta anterior es el siguiente:
**#Figura1**
[image: Figura #1]

Y el que estoy buscando obtener es:
**#Figura2**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradeceré saber si existe alguna otra forma de lograr el resultado de la #Figura2** , o que es lo que estoy haciendo equivocadamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que agrupes por `[detrec].[iddestino]` y obtengas la suma de los demas campos. Si todavía apareciera un valor 'NULL' puedes solucionarlo con IsNull().

```
  , sum(case when [enrec].[origenenvios] = [detrec].[iddestino]
        then IsNull([detrec].[nobulto],0) else 0 end) as [nobultorecibido]
```

Otra cosa, no es recomendable (aunque posible), el uso de BETWEEN con fechas, basicamente porque tienes que estar truncado la fecha, y usando caracteres.

```
select
    [detrec].[iddestino]
  , sum(case when [enrec].[origenenvios] = [detrec].[iddestino]
        then [detrec].[nobulto] else 0 end) as [nobultorecibido]
  , sum(case when [enrec].[origenenvios] = [detrec].[iddestino]
        then [detrec].[peso] else 0 end) as [peso]
  , sum(case when [enrec].[origenenvios] <> [detrec].[iddestino]
        then [detrec].[nobulto] else 0 end) as [nobultoenviado]
  , sum(case when [enrec].[origenenvios] <> [detrec].[iddestino]
        then [detrec].[peso] else 0 end) as [peso2]
from
    [recibos] [enrec]
        inner join [recibosdetalle] [detrec]
            on [detrec].[idrecibo] = [enrec].[idrecibo]
        inner join [destinos] [dest]
            on [dest].[iddestino] = [detrec].[iddestino]
where 
    [enrec].[idservicio] = '1'
    and [fecharecibo] >= cast('2017/01/13' as date)
    and [fecharecibo]  < cast('2017/01/14' as date)
group by
  [detrec].[iddestino];
```

Comment: En un principio pensé lo mismo, pero si ves el resultado que quiere el op, se puede ver que no está agrupado exclusivamente por `iddestino`

Comment: @Lamak lo he visto, pero entiendo que la fila en amarillo muestra lo que realmente quiere.

Comment: sí, y más abajo muestra dos valores iguales para `iddestino`. Pero bueno, op aceptó tu respuesta, por lo que supongo que lo que posteó no es en verdad lo que quería

Comment: Esa era la respuesta que necesitaba , agrupar por destinos , los demas campos del group by los necesitaba por que sino me generaba error de agregación, ya que como en el CASE hacia uso de ellos por la funcion SUM plasmada en el condicional Then. Pero estando la funcion SUM antes del case, ya no es necesario usarlos en el Group by.

Comment: @Rotiux Entiendo. Pero la idea de cuando muestras una imagen diciendo: "necesito estos resultados", entonces deberías verificar que en efecto esos son los resultados que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Sin tener unos datos para probar es difícil, pero creo que el problema es que tienes el `sum` dentro de la condición y cuando es nulo es como un valor distinto más te lo separa. Yo probaría algo así:

```
sum(
   case when enrec.OrigenEnvios<>detrec.iddestino then DetRec.Nobulto else 0
end) as NoBultoEnviado
```

Lo tendrías que poner en todos los `case`.

prueba y me cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas con tu consulta. Primero que todo, no es necesario que uses `DISTINCT`, si ya estás usando `GROUP BY`.

Por otro lado, no es claro, el por qué estás agrupando por 3 columnas, de las cuales sólo una no está de alguna forma en una función de agregación.

Tu problema principal, sin embargo, es el hecho que deberías usar la expresión `CASE` **dentro** de la función de agregación (en este caso, `SUM`). Reescribiendo tu consulta, sería:

```
SELECT  detrec.iddestino,
        DetRec.iddestino, 
        Enrec.origenenvios,
        SUM(CASE 
              WHEN enrec.origenenvios = detrec.iddestino THEN 
              DetRec.nobulto
            END) AS NoBultoRecibido, 
        SUM(CASE 
              WHEN enrec.origenenvios = detrec.iddestino THEN 
              DetRec.peso
            END) AS Peso, 
        SUM(CASE 
              WHEN enrec.origenenvios <> detrec.iddestino THEN 
              DetRec.nobulto 
            END) AS NoBultoEnviado, 
        SUM(CASE 
              WHEN enrec.origenenvios <> detrec.iddestino THEN 
              DetRec.peso
            END) AS Peso 
FROM dbo.Recibos EnRec 
INNER JOIN dbo.Recibosdetalle DetRec 
       ON DetRec.idrecibo = EnRec.idrecibo
INNER JOIN dbo.Destinos Dest 
       ON Dest.iddestino = DetRec.iddestino
WHERE  fecharecibo BETWEEN '20170113' AND '20170113' 
AND enrec.idservicio = '1' 
GROUP  BY EnRec.idservicio, 
          DetRec.iddestino, 
          Enrec.origenenvios;
```

Me tomé la libertad de agregar el prefijo del esquema a las tablas, además de terminar la consulta con un `;`.
También eliminé el `CONVERT` en la columna `fecharecibo`, ya que como estaba, no podrías usar un índice si es que existía en esa columna.